# Find row and column name of a specific value of a tibble

Tags: r, tibble

First I have found the min and max value of a `tibble`:

```
library(dplyr)
name <- c("a","b")
x <- c(1,2)
y <- c(3,4)
df <- as_tibble(data.frame(name,x,y))
min_max <- df %>%
  select(-name) %>%
  summarize(min(.), max(.))
```

In this case min=1 and max=4

```
> min_max
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  `min(.)` `max(.)`
     <dbl>    <dbl>
1        1        4
```

How can I find the row and column names of min and max? The answer in this case should be ("a",x) and ("b",y). I tried `which` with no result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `base R`, we can use `which` with `arr.ind` to get the row/column indices

```
which(df[-1] == min(df[-1]), arr.ind = TRUE)
which(df[-1] == max(df[-1]), arr.ind = TRUE)
```

Comment: Using these indices how can I get the row and column names of df?

Comment: @sbac  m1 <- which(df[-1], ..); row.names(df)[m1[,1]]` and `colnames(df)[-1][m1[,2]]

Comment: In this case it was better `df$name[m1[,1]]` instead of row.names.